# Use singleton classes in c++

Tags: c++

I created a singleton class

```
  class AreaDataRepository {
private:
    AreaDataRepository();
    AreaDataRepository(const AreaDataRepository& orig);
    virtual ~AreaDataRepository();

    Way onGoingWay;
public:
    static AreaDataRepository& Instance()
    {
        static AreaDataRepository singleton;
        return singleton;
    }

    void SetOnGoingWay(Way onGoingWay);
    Way const & GetOnGoingWay() const;
};
```

---

```
        void AreaDataRepository::SetOnGoingWay(Way onGoingWay) {
        this->onGoingWay = onGoingWay;
    }

Way const & AreaDataRepository::GetOnGoingWay() const {
    return onGoingWay;
}
```

header file of Way

```
  class Way {
private:
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
public:
    Way();
    Way(const Way& orig);
    virtual ~Way();

    void SetName(std::string name);
    std::string const & GetName() const;

    void SetId(std::string id);
    std::string const & GetId() const;
};
```

Then i'm created a Way object and set vales of id and name.

```
Way wayNode;
wayNode.SetId("123");
wayNode.SetName("jan")
AreaDataRepository::Instance().SetOnGoingWay(wayNode);
```

After assign OngoingWay accessing it from another class.

```
std::cout << AreaDataRepository::Instance().GetOnGoingWay().GetId();
```

the vale is not printing.

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4325835d4e6185a8)

Comment: What's the output? Nothing?

Comment: Way has a virtual destructor and a copy constructor but no copy-assignment operator. That's a bit suspect.

Comment: I removed AreaDataRepository(const AreaDataRepository& orig);
    virtual ~AreaDataRepository();
and tried, but same result.

Comment: You need to show enough code so that we can reproduce your issue. That means at least the setters of Way (add the getters while you're at it). (And read up on the "rule of three" which my previous comment referred to, although that doesn't seem to be your problem here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going psychic here.... and I divine that your implementation of `SetId` is like this:

```
void SetId(std::string id) { id = id; }
```

that does not set the member variable, that sets the parameter to itself. And since your constructor most likely set the member variable `id` to `""` you're printing empty strings. Either change the name of the parameter (to `newId` for example) to avoid the conflict or change the implementation to:

```
void SetId(std::string id) { this->id = id; }
```

As *proof* of this claim here's [the result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/279bfa0b067b0c62) for the first version, as you see it prints nothing. And here is [the result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4325835d4e6185a8) for the second, as you can see it prints the number.

The problem boils down to this: you have function parameter names that are the same as the name of your member variables and the function parameters are shadowing/hiding the member variables.

The only place this cannot happen is in a constructor's initialization list:

```
class Foo {
    int x;
public:
    Foo(int x): x(x) {} // <-- this works
    void SetX(int x) { x = x; } // <-- this won't the parameter is hiding the member variable
};
```

[Demo for the above snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c63a34687fc6fae)

Comment: "Circumstantial evidence", not "proof", but I do agree with this answer. :)

Comment: I have already added that "void SetId(std::string id) { this->id = id; }" implementation to the way.cpp file. I set  

AreaDataRepository()= default;
    AreaDataRepository(const AreaDataRepository& orig)= default;
    virtual ~AreaDataRepository()= default;

Way()= default;
    Way(const Way& orig)= default;
    virtual ~Way()= default;
    
to default as you mention in your example now its working, thanx

Comment: "The only place this cannot happen is in a constructor's initialization list" I think what you mean is that's the only place it _can_ happen.

Comment: @Léo I was referring to shadowing, the only place it won't happen is in the initialization list.

Comment: I see, sorry. I won't argue about this, after all I'm not a native speaker, but I would have used _won't_ instead of _cannot_.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` is buffered in most implementations, if not in all. That means, the stream will wait for you to end a line before writing out any data. So, you can easily fix this by changing your output statement to

```
 std::cout << AreaDataRepository::Instance().GetOnGoingWay().GetId() << std::endl;
```